# Oracle Query to Force results with default 2 years filter

Tags: sql, oracle

experts i want to force my reuslts with always 2 years default filter applied, regardless of user selects that date range or not

below is my approach. is there a better (optimal) way to write this

```
WITH forcedate as (
Select *
  From emp r
Where
   r.empdate >= to_date(20171019, 'YYYYMMDD')
  And r.empdate <= to_date(20181027, 'YYYYMMDD')
    )
  Select * From forcedate t
  where
  t.empid = 187
--below is the OPTIONAL bind variable for user input
AND t.empdate >= to_date(20171119, 'YYYYMMDD')
  And t.empdate <= to_date(20181227, 'YYYYMMDD');
```

Comment: hi, I believe you can use between and syntax, but before that can you explain what is your 2 year date range is this static? thanks.

Comment: @Nick yes the default 2 year is current date -1 to current date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to filter data twice, use functions `greatest()` and `least()`:

```
with dates as (select date '2017-10-19' d1, date '2018-12-27' d2 from dual)
select * 
  from emp
  join dates on empdate between greatest(d1, nvl(:input_1, d1)) and least(d2, nvl(:input_2, d2))
  where empid = 187
```

Comment: What will happen if the user enters beyond 2 years range? Can we enforce like should they key in beyond current date-1 to current date we use our default date?

Comment: If user enters date lower than our minimum date then our date has greater priority. If he enters second date greater than maximum then our date has also greater priority.  Please look carefully how condition is build.